# Python: How to efficiently do operations using different rows of the same column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My goal is that by given  a value on a row (let's say 3), look for the value of a given column 3 rows below. Currently I am perfoming this using for loops but it is tremendously inefficient.

I have read that vectorizing can help to solve this problem but I am not sure how.

My data is like this:

`Date DaysToReception Quantity QuantityAtTheEnd
20/03     3             102
21/03     -             88
22/03     -             57
23/03     5             178
24/03`

And I want to obtain:

`Date DaysToReception Quantity QuantityAtReception
20/03     3              102         178
21/03     -              88
22/03     -              57
23/03     5              178
24/03
...`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: * It is important to point out that the number of rows I search the value below depends on the value "DaysToReception" has

Answer (score 0):

If you have unique date or DaysToReception, you can actually use Map/HashMap where the key will be the date or DaysToReception and the values will be other information which you can store using a list or any other appropriate data structure.

This will definitely improve the efficiency.

As you pointed out that "number of rows I search the value below depends on the value "DaysToReception", I believe "DaysToReception" will not be unique. In that case, the key to your Map will be the date.

Comment: Thanks! I used map like you mentioned and it worked out

Comment: No problem @alejandropareja

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of to do this in pandas is the following:

```
# something like your dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(date=['20/03', '21/03', '22/03', '23/03'],
                       days=[3, None, None, 5,],
                       quant=[102, 88, 57, 178]))
# get the indexs of all days that aren't missing
idxs = df.index[~pd.isnull(df.days)]
# get number of days to go
values = df.days[idxs].values.astype(int)
# get index of three days ahead
new_idxs = idxs+values
# create a blank column
df['quant_end'] = None 
# Now fill it with the data we're after
df.quant_end[idxs] = df.quant[new_idxs]
```